# converting epoch time from decimal to hex in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, type-conversion

I want to convert the epoch time in binary to hex. I am able to do this in the command line by the following command

```
# epoxy time in decimal
me@bof:/auto/homes$ date +%s
1400687648

# epoxy time in hex
me@bof:/auto/homes$ printf "%x\n" $(date +%s)
537ccc3b
```

Now I want to do the above inside a Makefiles, I am trying to use the $(shell ) command, but I am missing something.

```
identifier:
        $(shell date +%s) 
        $(shell printf "%x\n" $(date +%s))
```

Could sombody help me with the above.
Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to put `shell` for the call of `date`

```
identifier:
    printf "%x\n" $(shell date +%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use `$(shell ...)` functions inside a recipe?  Every recipe is *already* run in a shell... why do it twice?  I see this all the time and I don't know where it comes from.

Try:

```
identifier:
        date +%s
        printf "%x\n" $$(date +%s)
```

Comment: Thank you that is a valid point and I accept it, i suppose Pavel updated his answer with your view point. Thanks again